# How to design the code that builds an sql query statement from a 'user friendly' UI?

Tags: c#, sql, user-interface

I have inherited a c# (wpf) project where part of the code is a user friendly UI (list boxes, radio buttons,sliders, etc.) for a non SQL person that creates a SQL query statement ... then queries a DB and returns the results.

The code to create the SQL basically walks thru the UI components and concatenates a string.

I'm slowing finding either bugs in the code and\or misinterpretations of the what was needed.

I want to update the code to a more elegant and maintainable state.  Are there any:

- 'design patterns' for this?
- best practices?
- examples of good code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Many wrote code like that when .net started; there are indeed many design patterns to move on from this.

Firstly, the project mixes c# and sql syntax. Separate those to halve the code size and double the elegance. Also to remove sql injection possibilities.

- identify what the final sql typically looks like. Might be

  ```
  select a,b,c from d join e join f where x and y and z
  ```
- write a stored procedure on the sql side to encapsulate this, passing parameters x, y , z
- change the c# code to call the stored procedure instead of the sql statement
- c# debugging can now involve just viewing the parameters you end up with when you get to call the sql statement
- on the sql side, the next step is to move the table joins and any static where clauses into a view, which will further simplify the stored procedure and also give the sql server more opportunity to pre-optimise the data selection.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any particular design-patterns for this, but if I was to implement something of this kind, I think I would try to create a sort of abstract representation of each SQL-operation that I would need to work with; perhaps something like the way **[SQLite documents it's queries](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)**.

Thinking in this way may be helpful when creating data structures to represent your queries.